# How can I save an array in one column?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following table in my database.

```php
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('url');
    $table->string('requirements');
    $table->string('coverImage');
    $table->string('domain');
    $table->text('feedbacks');
    $table->text('technologies_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to put in my `technologies_id` an array for instance:

```
technologies_ids: [1,2,3]
```

I tried the following.

```php
$project = new Project;
$project->title = $request->title;
$project->url = $request->url;
$project->requirements = $request->requirements;
$project->coverImage = $request->coverImage;
$project->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
$project->domain = $request->domain;
$project->feedbacks = $request->feedbacks;
$project->technologies_id = json_encode($request->technologies_id);
$project->services_id = $request->services_id;
```

**Error**

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `projects`

Comment: you have to store comma separated string when you store and when you get it would be convert into array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Project model add

```
protected $casts=['technologies_id'=>'array']
```

remove json_encode

```
$project->technologies_id = $request->technologies_id;
```

and in your blade file

technologies_id must be an array in checkbox or select

```
 name="technologies_id[]"
```

when you store data will be encoded automatically and decoded when get from database

Read this in the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: sorry, I was at work.
>>I tried now and I received this in my postman:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `projects`

Comment: I put technologies_id[0] = 1,
and technologies_id[1] = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the array so it can be a string.

```
$technologies_id = serialize(json_encode($request->technologies_id);
```

Then if you want to convert it to array again just use `unserialize($array)`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you store data in column use `implode()`

```
$project->technologies_id = implode(",",$request->technologies_id);
```

Then when you fetch or get data from column use `explode()`

```
$project = Project::find(1);
$techonolgy_ids = explode(',',$project->technologies_id);
```